# RODBC connections/functions work in normal script but fail inside Shiny reactive function

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, shiny

I am learning Shiny, and trying to build a simple shiny web app to help my team QA and visualize data. Our data is stored in Access databases on a file server. In normal R scripts, I can connect to the databases just fine with odbcConnectAccess2007("//Path/To/Wherever"), however, when run within a shiny reactive function, some part of the data download process fails after less time than it would take to download the data.

```
#Works fine outside of shiny
#'site' is a data frame that includes paths/tables/queries for a relevant data set
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007(site$db_path)
check.data <- sqlFetch(channel = conn, site$query_name, as.is = TRUE)
odbcClose(conn)
head(check.data, 5)
#Data displays just fine...

#Inside shiny functions, suddenly it fails
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "dropdown", label = "Sites", choices = sites$dropdown_name),
actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Go"),
tableOutput("CWL"))

server <- function(input, output){
observeEvent(input$selector, {
site <- sites[sites$dropdown_name == input$selector,]

conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007(site$db_path)
check.data <- sqlFetch(channel = conn, site$query_name, as.is = TRUE)
odbcClose(conn)
})

tabledata <- eventReactive(input$button, {
head(check.data, 5)
})

output$CWL <- renderTable({tabledata()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#error in head(check.data, 5) : object 'check.data' not found
```

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some kind of timing issue with the reactive functions and the ODBC connection?

Comment: How many databases are you connecting to?  And is it really necessary for the database connection to be defined in a reactive context?  Perhaps you could define your connection so it is more static.

Comment: The `sites` data frame contains, among other things, paths to the 50 or so separate DBs that our data is kept in. Pulling from each database dynamically would reduce wait time a lot compared to just grabbing everything at once. (I also want to move away from doing our databases this way, but this is what we're doing for now, haha).

Comment: I was actually going to suggest defining all of the connections up front, and only selecting which connection to use dynamically.  But that doesn't make much sense with 50 databases.

Comment: My main concern is why it's erroring out immediately. I figure it's some kind of timing issue with trying to render the table before the connection has been established/the data has been downloaded. It takes 5 or so seconds to download the data under normal circumstances and the error message appears one or two seconds after selecting the dropdown menu entry.

Comment: `check.data` is local to the context you supply to `observeEvent`. It's not going to be visible to some other context, like the one you give to `eventReactive` unless you assign it to the global name space with `<<-` or (what I think you want to do) is use `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent` and make it return `check.data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment for why you're getting that error. You probably want to do something like this:

```
sites <- ????

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "dropdown", label = "Sites", choices = sites$dropdown_name),
    actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "Go"),
    tableOutput("CWL")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    D <- eventReactive(input$selector, {
        site <- sites[sites$dropdown_name == input$selector,]
        conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007(site$db_path)
        on.exit(odbcClose(conn))
        sqlFetch(channel = conn, site$query_name, as.is = TRUE)
    })

    tabledata <- eventReactive(input$button, {
        head(D(), 5)
    })

    output$CWL <- renderTable({
        tabledata()
    })
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Matt. I knew I should have tried to learn Shiny before you left!